# How do I find out the highest number that commas had appeared in a row in a single column in a data frame in R?

Tags: r

I want to find out the maximum amount comma had appeared in a row in a single column.

For example,

```
     Cars
1    Bugatti (4)","Ferrari (7)","Audi (10)
2    Toyota (6)
3    Tesla (9)","Mercedes(8)
4    Suzuki (11)","Mitsubishi (19)","Ford (7)","BMW (6)
```

For the table column above, the maximum number a comma had appeared in a row is 3, and it is on row 4. How do I achieve this on a much more larger data (4000+ rows)?

Comment: Please share your data as a `dput` for better reproducibility. Use `dput(head(df,n))`.

Comment: I tried using the function that you mentioned but unfortunately, the output is very long. I tried this: `dput(head(clinical_ann_md[, c(12)]))`. I'm still very new at R. Do you know what I'm doing wrong? For context, I use R studio

Comment: Use `dput(head(clinical_ann_md))` and share the output in your question.

Comment: I face the same problem, the console would not display everything from that function because the output is very long. I think part of the problem is attributed to the fact that each row contains very long sentences (could possibly be up to 100+ words). I'm open to any other suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `gregexp()` to return a vector of the positions of the comma(s) in each string.  Then you can apply the `length()` function to count up the commas:

```
sapply(gregexpr(",", df$cars), length)
## 2 1 1 3
```

To answer the exact question asked, just wrap the above line of code in `max()` to determine the maximum number of times a comma appeared in one of your strings.

---

The above actually returns a "1" when a "0" is expected.  There is probably a more elegant solution, but here's a function that will handle zeros correctly:

```
count_commas <- function(x) {
    y <- sapply(gregexpr(",", x), as.integer) # get position of commas
    y <- lapply(y, function(y) if(y[1] == -1) NULL else y) # replace zeros
    return( sapply(y, length) ) # return count of commas
}

count_commas(df$cars)
# 2 0 1 3
```

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to remove the non-comma characters and calculate the number of chars.

I have no clue which class of object you are using for `cars`. Assuming your input is

```
cars <- c(' Bugatti (4)","Ferrari (7)","Audi (10)','Toyota (6)','Tesla (9)","Mercedes(8)','Suzuki (11)","Mitsubishi (19)","Ford (7)","BMW (6)')
```

then you can use `nchar(gsub("[^,]","", cars))` to get the number of commas of each row.